# CSS translate makes my input stop working

Tags: html, css

My input does not work. But if I remove the translate the input works but the input field is no longer centered dynamically.

I appreciate any help.

```css
.form-group {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  padding-bottom: 0vh;
  text-align: center;
}

.line-input {
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <input type="link" class="line-input" name="submit_link" placeholder="link">
</div>
```

Comment: I took the liberty of moving your styles to the CSS panel. Please do yourself a favor and don't use inline styles. They're a pain across the board.

Comment: Please revise your post to explain what "doesn't work" means, as it seems fine to me. See [ask] for tips.

Comment: Also, zero values should not have units attached (as in `0vh`).

Comment: And `link` is not a valid input type. Did you mean `url`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i fixed it by styling the input element with `z-index: 10`

Comment: There's nothing in your question to indicate that this is needed. Therefore, your solution is for a non-existent problem. Please revise your question post to actually show the problem, or just delete it. It offers no value to the community as it is.